# php artisan test fails immediately

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu, phpunit

The command `php artisan test` is failing immediately and throwing the error

```
Typed property DOMDocument::$documentElement must not be accessed before initialization
```

I've changed nothing from the default test cases, and I am running the command from the root folder of the project.

I am currently on **Ubuntu** with **php 8.1** installed.